# Django Error: local variable 'fav' referenced before assignment

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I got an error in Djang, When I try to pass the **favourite_add** to ajax I got
local variable 'fav' referenced before assignment

```
def favourite_add(request, id):
data = {}
video = get_object_or_404(Video, id=id)

if request.method == "POST":
    account = request.user.id
    if video.favourites.filter(id=account.id).exists():
        fav = False
        video.favourites.remove(account)
    else:
        video.favourites.add(account)
        fav = True
data["fav"] = fav
print(data)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: can you add your ajax request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indent `data["fav"] = fav` so that it is within the outer-most if-block.

currently `fav` only exists if a POST request is made so it will error if you make a GET request. I'm guessing you are making a GET request with your ajax function instead of a POST request.

```py
def favourite_add(request, id):
data = {}
video = get_object_or_404(Video, id=id)

if request.method == "POST":
    account = request.user.id
    if video.favourites.filter(id=account.id).exists():
        fav = False
        video.favourites.remove(account)
    else:
        video.favourites.add(account)
        fav = True
    data["fav"] = fav
print(data)
return JsonResponse(data)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, this returned nothing  `{}`

Comment: Yes you have to make a post request to get fav. If you don't want that then get rid of the outer-most if-block.